# $5$ dimensional space over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, lie-groups

When coming up with a double cover of $SO(5)$, I used conjugation by matrices of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} r & q\\ \overline{q} & r \end{pmatrix}$$ where $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $q$ is a quaternion. These matrices are clearly $5$ dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$, but I'm wondering if someone can identify this space by name so that I can find more information.

**Edit:** I should have also added that for any matrix $A$ of this form, $A=A^*$ where $*$ denotes conjugate transpose. However, this requirement follows from how $A$ was defined, so mentioning it again doesn't add information, but rather is a (potentially) useful observation.

Comment: how do you get to your matrix is 5d? $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{H}$

Comment: For a matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} r&q\\\overline{q}& r\end{pmatrix}\sim (r,q)\sim (r,x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb{R}^5$. Why would this not be 5 dimensional?

Comment: because $r_q=r + i.r_1+j.r_2+k.r_3$ with $r_1,r_2,r_3=0$

Comment: Could you explain what your matrix notation means, perhaps by taking $r$ real and $q = x + iy + zj + wk$ a general quaternion and writing out all the entries of $A$ (instead of writing a block matrix)? Or are you viewing quaternions as real $4 \times 4$ matrices, and your matrix $A$ is $8 \times 8$? In any case, how ostensibly is the $5$-dimensional vector space of all $A$ related to a double cover of the compact $10$-dimensional group $SO(5)$? Thanks. :)

Comment: @user86418 Sure. Consider the map $Sp(2)\to SO(5)$ defined by conjugation $P\mapsto PAP^\dagger$ where $\dagger$ is conjugate-transpose, and $A$ is one of the matrices in question. This map preserves the inner product $\left<A,B\right>=\dfrac{1}{2}Tr(AB)$ and it has kernel $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @user1227849937: Thank you; the preposition threw me: "conjugation _of_ matrices of the form", not "conjugation _by_ matrices of the form". :) It might be worth adding the details of your comment to the question body, unless you mentioned the double-covering of $SO(5)$ merely for context...? Anyway, those matrices have no name I'm aware of, but I'm no expert.

Comment: Yeah, I only mentioned $SO(5)$ to give context for why I'm interested in the matrices in question. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: You are not conjugating *by* matrices of that form, you are conjugating matrices of that form *by* matrices in ${\rm Sp}(2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few other interpretations, but I believe you are describing a system very similar to the **root system $D_5$**.

From the Wikipedia definition of [$SO_5(\mathbb{R})$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO%285%29), we have that :

> SO(5) is a simple Lie group of dimension 10

which takes us to the [Poincaré Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group).

The page on [Simple Lie Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group) leads to [Dynkin Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group#Classification_by_Dynkin_diagram) and the next chapter defines several relations between Dynkin diagrams and various groups.

In the list we have $B_2$ corresponds to $SO(5)$, and we can find a description of $B_2$ at the link to [Root Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system).

Neither of these seem to answer your question.

Further down the list, however, we also find that $D_5$ corresponds to $SO(10)$, which seems to be consistent with your development of a double covering of $SO(5)$.

I have found two references which explore the $D_5$ root system.

- [Conformal Invariance and String Theory](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aGHJbHKNVXoC&pg=PA428&lpg=PA428&dq=root%20system%20D5&source=bl&ots=aNLuHOM1lc&sig=e3O4WWPvAPLO3Ev6D9u56Bz15c0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zPRNVb-VCdLi7Qb8hoDIBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=root%20system%20D5&f=false), page 428 onwards.
- [A FAMILY OF MARKED CUBIC SURFACES AND THE ROOT SYSTEM D5](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.236.8252), by Elisabetta Colombo and Bert Van Geemen

Comment: Thanks for the references. I'll award you the bounty unless something more illuminating comes up by the time limit.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is close to nonsense: the Poincaré group, $SO(5)$ and $D_5$ don't have a lot to do with each other, except for some numerology.

Comment: I agree with Jose.

Answer (score 6):

I feel compelled to write this answer, based on the fact that the answer which was accepted makes no sense.

What the OP mentions seems to be an embedding of $\mathbb{R}^5$ inside the space $M$ of hermitian $2\times 2$ matrices over the quaternions, which is $Sp(2)$-equivariant: where $Sp(2)$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^5$ via the canonical double cover $Sp(2) \to SO(5)$ and acts on $M$ by the conjugation.

This is analogous to the following well-known construction.

You can exhibit the double cover $SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \to SO(3,1)_0$ as follows. You identify $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the real vector space $H$ of hermitian $2\times 2$ matrices.  (Minus) the determinant of a hermitian $2 \times 2$ matrix defines a quadratic form on $H$ coming from an inner product of signature $(3,1)$.  Define an action of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ on $H$ by $h \mapsto s h s^\dagger$, for $h \in H$ and $s  \in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$.  This is a linear transformation of $H$ which preserves the determinant (since $s$ has unit determinant) and hence defines an element of $O(3,1)$.  Since $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is connected, it actually defines a surjective map $SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \to SO(3,1)_0$ to the identity component.  The kernel of this map is the group of order $2$ generated by $-I$.

The analogy breaks down in that there is no quaternionic determinant in general, but perhaps for matrices in $M$ it can be defined.  I have not checked.

There are similar double covers which can be explicitly described in this way: e.g., $SL(2,\mathbb{R}) \to SO(2,1)_0$ and $SL(2,\mathbb{H}) \to SO(1,5)_0$.